# Apply XSL to layout XML at build time?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

Is there any way to apply an XSL stylesheet to the layout XML files in res/layout/ at build time so the resource compiler sees only the transformed output instead of the actual files on the hard drive?

Why: layout_width and layout_height have no default, everything requires them, and manually specifying them for every. single. widget. is. slowly. driving. me. insane.

So... the idea I came up with was to use XSLT to automatically and transparently add layout_width and layout_height attributes having a value of "wrap_content" to any tag that lacks them at build time. I'd be happy, and ADT will never know the difference. :-)

Comment: This sounds like a very good idea! I hope someone can tell how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to apply an XSL stylesheet to the layout XML files in res/layout/ at build time so the resource compiler sees only the transformed output instead of the actual files on the hard drive?

Customize your Ant `build.xml` file to do whatever you want. Ant even has an `xslt` task you can try to use.

> layout_width and layout_height have no default, everything requires them

They sometimes have defaults, depending on their parent. `TableLayout` gives all children `fill_parent` and `wrap_content` for width and height, respectively. `TableRow` gives all children `wrap_content` for both width and height. Those defaults can be overridden in your layout XML file if needed.

Comment: i forgot there was a ready made build.xml produced by the plugin :-)

Comment: Does Eclipse actually *use* that build.xml file somehow? I was under the impression that Eclipse with ADT has a totally alien build process.

Comment: @Bitbang3r: Eclipse doesn't use `build.xml`. You use `build.xml` via Ant from the command line.

Comment: Hmmm. I have to take another look at nbAndroid and see whether they've fixed the problems with external libraries, signing, autocomplete, and Android API javadocs. If they've fixed those problems, I can celebrate and officially categorize Netbeans (for Android) as my best and favorite Christmas present :)  Otherwise, I'm going to keep hunting for a solution that won't break Eclipse's build process (it seems to really, REALLY freak out when files change behind its back... on the (rare) occasions when it even *notices* that they've changed and doesn't ignore the new file altogether...)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest a java program or a script, that will require you to abandon the 'old ways' of right click on the android project in eclipse and clikc on export as... you will have to use things like mavno ant to build your application, not so bad if you ask me... this way before your run the appt to gather your resoures you can you run your custom program that checks your xml for missing layout_width and laout_height completing the ones missing.

Another way is to use th same programe from within eclipse before you export your application.

In any case default width and height if you ask me is a bad practive, what will be your default ? wrap_content ? usually you do have to specify them in one way or another.
But you have some ideas her if you still wants your default  :-)

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't even mind them as much if they weren't so ungodly verbose. I could halfway live with a:ww="wrap" or a:hh="fill". (ww and hh, because it's easier to type and less ambiguous than a 2-letter code beginning with a letter that looks like a digit). It's one thing to use a verbose name for obscure tags and attributes that are only used occasionally, but fer god's sake, these are attributes required by nearly every single tag in the framework. It's ok to slightly complicate helloworld if it makes their next 10,000 uses more convenient and less painful ;-)